# Can't install Iron-Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i get this when i type mrt add iron-router in my meteor app
this is on a mac

smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.5.4

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:108
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url;
                                                   ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git

what can i do to install iron-router ?

Comment: Try again in a few minutes. Does it persist?

Comment: do you have git installed?

Comment: still get the same error this morning... is there some other way to install it ?

Comment: yes, i have git installed, use it on a variety of projects

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mrt uninstall --system
```

Then reinstall iron-router again.

If it still happen maybe the author forget to push tag. ( if newer version released)

If u want to use it right now. Clone it into your packages folder

Comment: I've met this before. I reinstall meteorite and do mrt uninstall --system

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
meteor add iron-router
```

This is the newer way to install Meteor packages.

Note:  Also make sure you run this command in the root directory of your Meteor project.